# Templates in DocTeX : Documenting and producing code within the macrocode environment

Tags: comments, dtx, docstrip

I'm writing a DocTeX file (*.dtx) to create a family of classes. From this file I am also generating and documenting the templates that illustrate their usage.

```
%\iffalse
%<*template>
%\fi
%
% There are now two versions of the \package{invoice} Package
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<VersionA>\documentclass{CustomInvoiceA}
%<VersionB>\documentclass{CustomInvoiceB}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%\iffalse
%</template>
%\fi
```

For the most part this is working well but I can't seem to shake the guards (HTML like tags) in the documented code and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

[image: Output showing HTML like guards]

From Scott Pakins' DTX tutorial (Invoke `texdoc --view dtxtut` from the command line to view at home) the following summary table is useful for determining where code will usually apply but the behavior is different within a `macrocode` environment.

[image: Scott Pakin : DTXTtut : Comment Table]

Is it possible to remove the `<GUARDS>` in the output (The first image) ? I know I could move the `<GUARDS>` from the `macrocode` environment into additional `\iffalse...\fi` but I would prefer not to pepper the document with these statements everywhere, perhaps there is another way.

Comment: what is your question exactly? the output you show is what I would expect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was hoping to remove the tags in the output, is this the expected behaviour ? (I updated the question to include one)

Comment: Normally the docstrip tags allow you to make multiple files but with a shared documentation, so without the tags the documentation would be very hard t follow, eg the image you show it would look like a document with two  `\documentclass` but as it is it document that two documents will be made, and shows the documentclass in each

Comment: Ah so I'm fighting the design, I wasn't sure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Coincidentally could one stylize the tags instead with say rounded rectangles in different colours or would that be a bit gaudy ?

Comment: the sf setting of `<VersionA>` comes from `\def\Module#1{\mod@math@codes$\langle\mathsf{#1}\rangle$}`  so change that `\mathsf` to some fancy tcolorbox box setting and see if you like it.....

Comment: I'll mess around with it this afternoon. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is "Nope Dummy !!! Don't fight the design". I'll run through the document and fix my really bad tag name choices instead.